# Python - Remove files with same name but different extension

Tags: python, image, png, data-cleaning

I am making an inventory of the pictures I have within a specific folder and I want to remove some unwanted pictures.

The pictures I need to get rid of are *.mov* files that represent the **live status** of the picture. When using iPhone and transferring the pictures to my laptop I get **two files per picture**: one of them is a *.png* file, which is the **picture as such**, and another one is a *.mov* file with the same name, which represents the **live status of the photo**. Videos also possess *.mov* extension when taken with iPhone but I do not want to remove them, only pictures.

I want to find all *.mov* files with the same name as a *.png* file, and remove the *.mov* file. However, not all *.mov* files should be removed as some of them are videos and do not have a correspondent *.png* file.

Here is the code for doing the inventory so far, but I do not know how to proceed with the removal part in a simple manner:

```
import re
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, isfile, join, split, realpath

directory = r'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Viajes\Eslovaquia\Bratislava'

current_directory_name = split(split(realpath(directory))[1])[1]
parent_directory_name = split(split(realpath(directory))[0])[1]
print(current_directory_name, 'directory can be found within', parent_directory_name, 'directory.')
print('-----')

only_folders = [folder for folder in listdir(directory) if isdir(join(directory, folder))]
only_files = [file for file in listdir(directory) if isfile(join(directory, file))]

if len(only_folders) == 0 and len(only_files) == 0:
    print(current_directory_name, 'directory is empty.')
elif len(only_folders) > 0 and len(only_files) == 0:
    print(current_directory_name, 'directory contains the following folders:', only_folders, 'and no files.')
elif len(only_folders) == 0 and len(only_files) > 0:
    print(current_directory_name, 'directory contains the following files:', only_files, 'and no other folders.')
elif len(only_folders) > 0 and len(only_files) > 0:
    print(current_directory_name, 'directory contains the following folders:', only_folders, '\n')
    print(current_directory_name, 'directory contains the following files:', only_files)
```

The output I get when running the code so far is this one:
[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You iterate through the files list. If a file name ends with `.mov` you check if the list contains a corresponding file with `.png` ending and if so, delete the mov-file.

Comment: Looking at your example, you mean .JPG, not .PNG.

Comment: Sort by name. Then step through the list, removing a .MOV if and only if it is immediately preceded by a .JPG of the same name. If it is immediately preceded or followed by a file with the same name but a different extension that is not .JPG, you may want to delete those as well. I would print an alert in those cases, to see what the extension is, and decide if I want to add those to my logic for deletion. Maybe you really do have .PNG's in there, in which case they would immediately _follow_ the .MOV.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are interested in working within a single directory, then my approach would be as follows:

1. First, I would use `glob.iglob` passing argument `r'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Viajes\Eslovaquia\Bratislava\*.png'` (this argument would be dynamically created) to create a generator that enumerates the full path name for all the PNG files. Since abc.png and ABC.PNG are equivalent files in Windows, I would convert these path names to lower case for improved matching. I would then construct a set from this generator for easy searching.
2. I would then create a second generator to enumerate all the MOV files in the directory.
3. For each MOV file see if a corresponding PNG files exists. If so, then delete the MOV file.

```py
from glob import iglob
from os.path import join, isfile, splitext
from os import unlink

directory = r'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Viajes\Eslovaquia\Bratislava'

# Since Windows's file system is case-insensitive convert all file names
# to lower case:
images = set(f.lower() for f in iglob(join(directory, '*.png')) if isfile(f))
movies = (f.lower() for f in iglob(join(directory, '*.mov')) if isfile(f))

for movie in movies:
    # For file \a\b\c.mov, construct \a\b\c.png:
    image = splitext(movie)[0] + '.png'
    if image in images:
        try:
            unlink(movie)
        except Exception:
            print('Unable to delete', movie)
        else:
            print('Successfully deleted', movie)
```

I do not warrant this code free of defects so review this code carefully before you run it.

Comment: @Mark Adler Uh, no. Maybe you are thinking some worst-case scenario but not the average case according to the good folks who give us Python. See [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: See [this simulation](https://ideone.com/ZF1KEl).

Comment: Ah. Didn't notice that `images` is a set.

Comment: @MarkAdler No need to look at the code. Just see my bullet **1.** where  I explicitly state I am creating a set.